# RestSharp with HTTP 2.0

Tags: c#, http, restsharp

I'm trying to make requests (GET/POST) using RestSharp with HTTP 2.0

With the following code generates HTTP 1.1 requests. The server is configured to support HTTP 2.0.

```
        var restClient = new RestClient(URL);
        IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(CONTEXT, Method.GET);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

Any thoughts on how to set explicitly the HTTP version to 2.0?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunatelly haven't found one. I've read that maybe I should do a native http call or maybe look for another library.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is old, but someone could be found my solution useful.

Actually (apr-2019) RestSharp doesn't support HTTP/2.0 request.

The only way I've found is use the standard `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage` to send the REST request, in this way:

```cs
var http2Handler = new Http2Handler();
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(http2Handler))
{
    var requestHttp = new HttpRequestMessage {
        RequestUri = new Uri(yourUrl),
        // ...
    };

    var responseHttp = httpClient.SendAsync(requestHttp).Result;
    // ... response elaboration
}
```

Where `Http2Handler` simply is:

```cs
public class Http2Handler : System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Version = new Version("2.0");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous: `var responseHttp = httpClient.SendAsync(requestHttp).Result;` You shouldn't use .Result to access the result. That can result in a deadlock. You should `await` the results. I suggest you read through the [Async Await Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Also, `HttpClient` [shouldn't be used with new/Dispose](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).