# Using http2 in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

Can you please tell me how to use http2 with RestSharp?
I tried to set up my own HttpClient and set the protocol settings for it, but it still doesn't work

I’ll make a reservation right away, the server supports http2 and if you use pure HttpClient everything works. But I would like to be able to use it with RestSharp.

RestSharp version 110.2.0

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Config.API_PATH);
httpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20;

RestClient testClient = new RestClient(httpClient);
```

Comment: They seem to use the httpclient internally starting from 107, so you don't have to pass your own httpclient in the constructor

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla I don't quite understand this section of the documentation
https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#reusing-httpclient

Plus, the IDE itself does not throw an error, and the base address is used from HttpClient

Comment: But have you tried the plain rest# client, with no http client injected?

Comment: @ Wiktor Zychla A simple RestClient connects via http1, this can be seen from the server logs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RestSharp with HTTP 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526637/restsharp-with-http-2-0)

Comment: @JHBonarius I saw this answer, but it is very outdated. HTTP2 support is native in .NET 7
And when using that solution, we do not use RestSharp